# How do I set a timeout on a Mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with a very large Mongo database, and I want costly queries like `MySet.find({})` to time out after 10 seconds.

I've tried setting a socket timeout on my connection, but the server crashes if the timeout is exceeded:

```
var options = {server: {socketOptions: {socketTimeoutMS: 10000}}};
var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db', options);
```

I've tried passing the [maxTimeMS](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html) option to the [find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) function, but that doesn't have any effect at all:

```
MySet.find({}, {}, {timeout: true, maxTimeMS: 10000}, function(err, doc) {});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using MongoDB 2.6 or higher?

Comment: `mongo --version` says `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8`.

Comment: Looks like Mongoose support for the `maxTimeMS` option was [added in 3.8.13](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#3813--2014-07-15). What's your Mongoose version?

Comment: Mongoose is at 3.8.24

Comment: MySet.find({}, {}, {maxTime: 10}, function(err, doc) {}) sort of works, but only for small values of maxTime. At first I thought that maxTime takes seconds or maybe tenths of a second, but the value 10 makes it time out virtually instantly and the value 100 makes it never time out.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with the [`Query#maxTime`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-maxTimeMS) method.

So in your case, you would call it as:

```
MySet.find({}).maxTime(10000).exec(function(err, doc) { ... });
```

You can confirm it's correctly setting the `maxTimeMS` option by enabling Mongoose debugging via `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and then you'll see console output for this query that looks like:

```
Mongoose: myset.find({}) { maxTimeMS: 10000, safe: true, fields: {} }
```

Comment: Is there an option to add this maxTime globally to all querys?

Comment: `maxTimeMS` is now documented by mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-maxTimeMS

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

```js
MySet.find({ $query: { /*Query here*/ }, $maxTimeMS: 10000 });
```

You can test with this query :

```js
MySet.find({ $query: {"$where": "sleep(100) || true"}, $maxTimeMS: 10000 });
```

---

## Why it works:

You can use [Query modifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/)

And especialy this one : [$maxTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/)

**Be careful** : this operator is deprecated in mongo Shell since v3.2

Answer (score -2):

This is the pattern I have started to use a lot.

```
// Default time out timeout in ms
const DEFAULT_TIME_OUT = 500;

// Default timeout message
const DEFAULT_MESSAGE = `Timeout fetching data(${DEFAULT_TIME_OUT}ms)`;

// Function that triggers a Promise's reject after a set amount of time
function timeoutReject(reject, message, timeout) {
  setTimeout(function(){

    // Reject the Promise if the time is reached
    reject(message || DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
  }, timeout || DEFAULT_TIME_OUT);
};

function youAreNotAuthentic() {
  // Logic to validate user and request return boolean
};

// Throw error if the user cannot access this data
function youCantTouchThis() {
  throw new Error('You cannot access this data.');
};

// Function to request data
function getDataById(_id) {
  // First check if this is authentic
  if (youAreNotAuthentic()) youCantTouchThis();

  // Return a Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Set a timeout to reject if we do not get a response in x time
    timeoutReject(reject, 'Custom Message', 300);

   // Could look like this to just use the defaults
   // timeoutReject(reject);

    // Query for the data
    Collection.findOne({ _id }).then(data => {

       // Resolve the Promise with the retrieved data
       resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

This way I have a default timeout applied to most requests but if I need to adjust on an per call basis then I can. Or I can be made aware of areas that need better indexing.

Comment: Some have suggested and approved the "single angled quote" to be a normal quote. This will not work. It is meant to be a templated string. ` is correct not `'`.

Answer (score -3):

I think this should work.

db.mycoll.find().maxTimeMS(50)

Comment: That would work for the native MongoDB driver, but it does not work for Mongoose.

Answer (score -8):

I finally got it working. First I prevent the server from crashing when the socket (i.e. a query) times out:

```
//don't crash the server if a query times out
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {});
```

Then, every time I want to query the database, I disconnect from and reconnect to the database, setting socketTimeoutMS to 10000:

```
mongoose.disconnect();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db', {
  server: {socketOptions: {socketTimeoutMS: 10000}}
});
MySet.find({}, function(err, doc) {});
```

This cuts off the query after precisely 10 seconds of execution.

Comment: Disconnect/reconnect on each query would be expensive right?

Comment: The overhead that you're paying by reconnecting on each query makes this approach unusable for everything but the simplest apps.