# Calling MongoDB find from Azure webjob nodejs does not call the callback function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-webjobs

I created a NodeJS webjob in azure that gets executed once a day.
In the run.js, I retrieve some documents from a MongoDB collection and need to execute some code for each document.
The job runs successfully, but doesn't work. (the code runs fine on my local machine)
Here is the relevant code.

```
var connectionString = config.MG_USER + ':' + config.MG_PWD + '@' + config.MG_SERVER + '/' + config.MG_DBNAME;
mongoose.connect(connectionString, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ');
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connected to DB'); //this shows up in the log.
        sendReminders();
    }
});

var sendReminders = function () {
    //read appointments from MongoDB
    var startDate = new Date(); // this is the starting date that looks like ISODate("2014-10-03T04:00:00.188Z")
    startDate.setSeconds(0);
    startDate.setHours(0);
    startDate.setMinutes(0);
    startDate.setMilliseconds(0);
    startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days');

    //console.log(startDate.toISOString());
    Appointment.find({appointmentDate: startDate}).populate("_userId").exec(function (err, appointments) {
        console.log('data'); //This NEVER executes
        if (err) {
            processError(err);
        }
        else if (!appointments.length) {
            console.log('no appointments');
            process.exit();
        }
        else {
            console.log(appointments.length + ' appointments');
            sendMessages(appointments);
        }
    });
};
```

The code inside the MongoDB find callback NEVER executes.
I'm stumped :(

Comment: Try setting a timeout on the request (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004445/how-do-i-set-a-timeout-on-a-mongoose-query ): does that make any error appear?

Comment: PS: consider modernizing your code, for example using promises (which are supported in Mongoose!). it will make it much more readable, without declaring functions outside of the scope in which they're used :)

Comment: Thanks, The code above is actually a simplification of what was there. I have the code in modules and I use Q with promises but when that didn't work, I just tried to get this to the simplest possible path. Also, the timeout is not an issue here because I have precisly one document in the collection right now

Comment: Does it run correctly locally? Recommend debugging it locally first and getting that running. If it runs locally but not in Azure, you can use the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to run your job directly from the command line in Azure. Just keep reducing/simplifying your code to find the issue. Likely one of your chained functions isn't working, causing your callback to not be invoked.

Comment: Yes, it runs locally with no problems.It seems that process.exit gets called even though there is still code execuing when it runs in Azure but not locally. If I take out the process.exit() call then it runs for 5 minutes (and works) and then azure throws an error because the app didn't have any cpu activity and kills the process

Comment: Which service you use to host your mongoDB database?