# Mongoose request infinite hang

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

***Context***:

- Mongoose v4.7.6
- MongoDB v3.2.11

I'm trying to handle errors related to my database in my software.

I'm stuck in the following problem: When the database is disconnected, mongoose request hang until it get reconnected.

---

***Here is what happend*:**

1. I launch my software
2. It connect to the database though *mongoose*
3. I *Ctrl+C* the *mongod* process
4. I get the *"Disconnect"* and *"Close"* event from mongoose
5. I launch a *find(...)* request
6. **Find request hang**

---

***What I've tried so far:***

I tried to use in my schema the option **bufferCommands**                   who according to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/unstable/docs/guide.html#bufferCommands) was supposed to make mongoose return an error if there is no available connection, but the result is the same.

---

***What is my code?***

```
   mongoose.createConnection(..., {
      server: {
        // We disable reconnect from mongoose
        auto_reconnect: false,

        socketOptions: {
          // For long running applictions it is often prudent to enable keepAlive.
          // Without it, after some period of time you may start to
          // see "connection closed" errors for what seems like no reason.
          // From mongoose documentation
          keepAlive: 1,
        },
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are thrown from the mongoose connection directly whenever there is a connection issue, the main server where you make the connection and there are several ways to handle it depending on what you want.

The find query you make is specifically for schema which in the end makes use of main connection object. You'll have to handle it that way for yourself and for users you'll have to configure a timeout for the request being made by them and send them appropriate response.

**Cancelling Request based on timeout**

This can be done on several levels, your server's logic, your client's end or the mongoose itself.

Follow this person's answer for setting timeout with mongoose, apparently it is not documented properly by mongoose.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609226/5225363

For server's logic, you can make a system for specific request that if there is no this then send a response back to client with something else.

On client if no response is received for a specific time then be assured that there is some problem.

p.s By default there is timeout setting for requests

Comment: Thx for responding to my question. I don't fully understand your answer. So my find query use the schema and then the main connection object. What can I do to cancel the request tho? Thx

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT timeout for the find function - this is what I wrote in the answer. If you don't get a response back for that specific request for a while then cancel the request.

Comment: Do you know how to cancel a request sent to mongoose?

Comment: I am updating this in the answer @GrégoryNEUT

Comment: So thanks. I did read your update. The things with setting a timeout in mongoose is that you don't make the difference between a big request that takes time and a request that should really timeout. I would have rather prefer the *bufferCommands* to work because it exactly answer my problem. If you can find why *bufferCommands* do not work I'll be very thankfull. Anyway I approve your answer.